# Getting path of java bundler on Mac

Tags: java, jarbundler

I have made an Mac application `MyApp.app` with `Jar Bundler`. Because I have an external jar, `lib/AutoUpdate.jar` that is in the same folder path as the `MyApp.app`, I need the current path of the `MyApp.app` to be able to run auto-updates.
Apparently:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Dose not work. I also tried:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
if(path.contains("/MyApp.app")){
   int i = path.indexOf("/MyApp.app");
   path = path.substring(0,i);
}
```

But this also seems to be incorrect path of the `MyApp.app`. Any ideas how to get the correct path or if I at least can debug the the `MyApp.app` to get a view of `System.out.println()` commands?

Comment: For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Applications/MyApp.app` for the location if it is in the given area, or you could use a Unix command to launch the jar at the desired directory (and not hardcode it into the `.jar` file).

`-x` is used for executables, but apps usually also work with `-d` and all work with `-e` commands.

To implement, place your `AutoUpdater.jar` with the other .jar files in `MyApp.app/contents/resources/java`. The `AutoUpdater.jar` should look something like this:

```
main()
{
    if [ -x Applications/MyApp.app];then
        cd Applications/MyApp.app/contents/resources/java
        java AutoUpdater.jar
        wait 86400
        main
    else
        wait 3600
    fi
}
main
```

The next bit of code will attempt to see if the app exists every hour and update daily if left running.

```
download()
{
    cd Applications/MyApp.app/contents/resources/java
    if ! curl -LO http://your.url.that.it.is.updating.from;then
        echo "Failed to download"
        wait 3600
    else
        wait 86400
    fi
}
```

You can completely remove `AutoUpdate.jar` by adding this to the code before the last line. Replace this:

```
java AutoUpdater.jar
wait 86400
```

... with this:

```
download
```

This is designed only for `JarBundler` apps. You should use this to replace the current .jar file.

```
if ! curl -LO http://cbukk.it/craftbukkit-dev.jar;
```

As a side note, the command `user.dir` usually gets `/Users/yourName` as the path. You could change this to use a global identifier in `JarBundler` like so:

```
String path = com.mycommpany.myapp;
```